# Is very slow update after initial install normal for Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda Navigator yesterday just to see what it was about. After install my current version was 1.7.0 (Windows 10 64 bit.) The first time I launched the Anaconda Navigator I was prompted to update. The available version is 1.8.3. I clicked the "Update Now" button. The updater has been running for 3 hours now. Is this normal and was this update necessary?

Comment: I have a very fast internet connection -- 300 MB/s

Comment: Shut it down. Will skip Anaconda for now.